# php Replace <a href=" or <a href=' with another URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm stuck as preg_matching is not always that easy as I'm totally not familiar with it.

I'm trying to replace all the

In example:

```
<a href="www.site1.com">Site1</a> => <a href="http://example.com?u=www.site1.com">Site1</a>
```

But the <a href can be written in many ways; a HREF or A href or double spaced <A  href etc... How can i manage this. Bear in mind, performance is key

I've tried the following with str_replace, but of course that does not cover all the <a href (capital non capitalized versions).

```
$str = '<a href="www.sitename1.com">sitename1</a><br /><a href="www.sitename2.com">sitename2</a><br /><A HREF="www.sitename3.com">sitename3</a>';

$Replace = str_replace('<a href="', '<a href="https://example.com/&i=1243123&r=', $str);

echo $Replace
```

Comment: You've tried a str_replace, how has your attempts with regular expressions gone?

Comment: What do you want to replace with what? i don't get it

Comment: Are you trying to replace the constant string with $str??

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1902010

Comment: @Rizier123 all '<a href='s should replaced like the second argument in the str_replace.

Comment: Please for all that is sacred just use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (PHP 5.3+):

```
$link = preg_replace_callback('#<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>#is', function ($match) {
    return sprintf(
        '<a%shref="%s"%s>',
        $match[1],
        'http://example.com?u=' . urlencode($match[2]),
        $match[3]
    );
}, '<a href="www.site1.com">Site1</a>');

echo $link;
```

Comment: Looks like this one works. Anybody that has comments to this? Why not use this instead of the dom parse if performance en speed are key?

Comment: You have to try them both and see which is faster. But I think this way is faster because this will not parse html and generate a traversable structure. Besides that, you will not iterate over the DOM neither manipulate it and regenerate modified HTML from structure.

Answer (score 1):

The only fully reliable way of doing this is to use a proper HTML parser.

Happily, PHP has one built-in.

You'd first load the HTML with DomDocument's `loadHTML` function: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Then search the parsed tree with XPath and manipulate the A tags: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php